# Не получается добавить WHERE в запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Этот запрос возвращает записи с 4 колонками: `id`, `alias`, `name`, `status`.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT t.id, t.alias, t.name,
 CASE WHEN at.tag_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS status
 FROM tbl_tag t LEFT JOIN tbl_article_tags at
 ON t.id = at.tag_id
```

Как добавить условие `WHERE status = 1`? Если его добавить, то mysql выдает ошибку:

> #1054 - Unknown column 'status' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`SQL Alias` - могут быть использованы для задания таблицам или столбцам других имен, используя для этого псевдоним. Использование псевдонимов может быть полезным, если имеются длинные или сложные имена таблиц или столбцов.

Когда Вы пишете `AS status` - Вы задаете имя для столбца, увы его нельзя использовать в условии `WHERE`. Поэтому решение поставленной задачи будет таким:

```
 SELECT
   DISTINCT
     t.id,
     t.alias,
     t.name,
   CASE
     WHEN at.tag_id IS NULL THEN 0
     ELSE 1
   END AS status
 FROM tbl_tag t 
 LEFT JOIN tbl_article_tags at ON t.id = at.tag_id
 WHERE at.tag_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: еще можно саб-запросом

Comment: @Vartlok, да, либо саб-запросом, но это будет более затратно.